# How to upload set of all the files in folder on flowForce server using system ftp store method?

Tags: file-upload, ftp, map-force

I have setup flow force server in my local pc and I was able to run couple of sample jobs. Then I try to setup FTP store job by providing required details. I was also able to upload specific file in to FTP server as well.

But now I need to know whether there is a possibility to upload all the files in particular folder in to target folder in FTP server. Appreciate if someone who have knowledge above flowforce server can share their thoughts about this.